# Sending objects via streams for my project isn't working, socket closed

Tags: java, networking, stream

The server:

```
public Server() throws IOException {
    socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while (true) {
        Socket client = socket.accept();
        Spooker.get().getWindow().append(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has connected.");
        if (inetAddrFound(client.getInetAddress().getHostName())) {
            System.out.println("Address found.");
            Thread thread = new Thread(new SpookerClient(client));
            threads.put(client, thread);
            thread.start();
        }

    }

}

private class SpookerClient implements Runnable {

    Socket sock;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public SpookerClient(Socket socket) {
        System.out.println("Creating Spooker client.");
        this.sock = socket;
        try {
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Client client;
        try {
            Spooker.get().getWindow().append("Finding object.");
            System.out.println("Finding object.");
            while ((client = (Client) ois.readObject()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Object found.");
                Spooker.get().getWindow().append("Object found.");
                if (keyFound(client.getKEY()) && idFound(client.getID())) {
                    Spooker.get().getWindow().append("Writing object.");
                    System.out.println("Writing object.");
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(Spooker.get().getConfiguration());
                    oos.flush();
                    threads.remove(sock);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The client:

```
public ClientConnection() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(decode(ADDR), Integer.parseInt(decode(PORT)));
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        oos.writeObject(new Client());
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new IncomingSpookerConfiguration());
        thread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class IncomingSpookerConfiguration implements Runnable {

    SpookerConfiguration configuration;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Trying..");
        try {
            while ((configuration = (SpookerConfiguration) ois.readObject()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && Spooker.get().getConfiguration() == null) {
                System.out.println("Configuration loaded.");
                Spooker.get().setConfiguration((SpookerConfiguration) ois.readObject());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println(Spooker.get().getConfiguration().getX());
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is that the socket is closed. I don't understand why.

What I am trying to do is this;

The client sends the server a Client class which contains a unique identifier (the CPUID, also [found here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0580.html)). The server checks if the client is registered - e.g. if their cpuid is on the database.

If the cpuid is on the database, the server sends back a "SpookerConfiguration" class, which essentially will be a class containing values that the client will use to create the GUI (e.g. size, title, default close op, etc.).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
    Client error:

Trying..
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:224)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek
(ObjectInputStream.java:2584)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek
(ObjectInputStream.java:2891)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte
(ObjectInputStream.java:2901)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1502)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at com.spooker.connection.ClientConnection$IncomingSpookerConfiguration.run
(ClientConnection.java:50)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Server error:

```
java.net.SocketException: 
Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at  java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain
(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode
(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException
(ObjectOutputStream.java:1580)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
at com.spooker.server.Server$SpookerClient.run(Server.java:65)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace on both sides.

Comment: A lot of things; it starts with the fact that you are writing rather complicated, hard to read code. It starts with things like: why are you creating **new** Object streams; although you already created some in the ctor of classes? Why are you mixing UI work with this code? Thing is: you worked hard to write code that is good at hiding what it is *really* doing. Doesn't really come as a surprise that you are now looking to other people to understand what your code is doing ...

Comment: @GhostCat I'm mixing UI work so that it is harder for people to crack my software - so that if they "remove" the authentication process (connecting to the server), the software won't have the GUI values (strings, ints, booleans etc) to create itself. Just a security measure.

Comment: @JimGarrison done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `socket closed` means that *you* closed the socket, and then continued to use it. Solution: don't.
2. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream. It throws `EOFException`. Your read loops are incorrect.
3. You must use the same object streams for the life of the socket.